# Yii2 - update record with child records

Tags: yii2

I have a form which allows the user to add many child records, in my case they are called "Items". When updating the master record, the user can add, edit or delete child records. Everything works fine, but I am looking for a better way to do this.

Currently, in my Update action, I first delete any existing child records. I then save all the child records from the form post.

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        // first delete all existing child records
        Item::deleteAll(['parent_id' => $model->id]);

        // get the new set of posted Items
        $items = Yii::$app->request->post('Item');

        if (!empty($items) && is_array($items)) {
            // save each Item
            foreach ($items as $index => $values) {
                $item = new Item();
                $item->attributes = $values;
                $item->parent_id = $model->id;
                $item->save();
            }
        }

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Form View:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <?php foreach ($model->items as $index => $item): ?>
        <?php echo Html::activeTextInput($item, "[$index]name"); ?>

        <!-- Example output -->
        <!-- <input id="item-0-name" name="Item[0][name]" value="Test" type="text"> -->

        <a href="#">Remove this Item</a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<a href="#">Add a new Item</a>
```

In the above `$model->items` refers to the relation in the parent model:

```
public function getItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Item::className(), ['parent_id' => 'id']);
}
```

When the user clicks "Add a new Item" it simply uses JavaScript to clone the last item and replaces its index with the next value.

Very often, the user does not change any child records. So the process of deleting and re-adding child records in that case is pointless.

What I want to know is, is there a way I can intelligently handle this? For example:

- Only delete child records if they do not exist in the POSTed Item array
- Only edit the child records if they are different to the ones in the database
- Only add new child records that do not currently exist in the database
- Otherwise leave everything as it is

Comment: Does `Item` model has some ID or unique field?

Comment: Just updated my original post. Item model has an ID primary key. In my form the `Item` is generated in a "tabular" array format (zero based).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`indexBy()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequeryinterface#indexBy()-detail) to define your relation to index related items by their ID:

```
public function getItems() {
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class, [/*...*/])->indexBy('id');
}
```

Then you can check if record with this ID already exist and do update/delete/create action:

```
// get the new set of posted Items
$items = Yii::$app->request->post('Item');
$existing = $model->items;

if (!empty($items) && is_array($items)) {
    // save each Item
    foreach ($items as $index => $values) {
        if (!isset($existing[$index])) {
            // create new item
            $item = new Item();
            $item->attributes = $values;
            $item->parent_id = $model->id;
            $item->save();
        } else {
            // update existing
            $existing[$index]->attributes = $values;
            $existing[$index]->save();
            // remove from $existing array as already processed
            unset($existing[$index]);
        }
    }

    // right now $existing has only existing and not updated items - it means
    // that they're not available in POST data so we should remove it
    foreach ($existing as $item) {
        $item->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: `!isset($existing[$index])` wont work, the form fields are populated using the default array index rather than the item `id` field, the first item will always have the index `0` even if that item already exists with the id `112` but since the field is created `item-0-name` it will assume the `id` is `0`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Are you sure about that? I've done some tests and it works correctly - index from `$index` is preserved on form submit. So as long `$index` in form represents ID of record, it should work correctly.

Comment: i think so, seeing the current form fields in the OP, are populated as `<?php foreach ($model->items as $index => $item): ?><?php echo Html::activeTextInput($item, "[$index]name"); ?>` the `$index` here isnt the `id` for the `item` table ? or am i wrong?

Comment: I think you're wrong, `$this->hasMany(Item::class, [/*...*/])->indexBy('id');` should ensure that `$model->items` will be indexed by item ID.

Comment: Hmm!  you are using `indexBy()` will index it according to the given column , totally missed that.